# Postgres - update command from CLI

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, command-line-interface

I need to create script in linux. There is command like:

```
psql -U postgres -d ticketon -c "UPDATE "user" SET "password" = 'test'"
```

When I put it to quotation marks, there is mistake. When out of quotation marks, there also is error. I have tried almost everything, but still without success. Do anyone know what is correct syntax?

Comment: Another good reason to avoid table (or column) names that need quoting...

Comment: Can't test, but I'd try `psql -U postgres -d ticketon -c "UPDATE \"user\" SET \"password\" = 'test'"`

Comment: I feel so strongly against needing to put double quotes around names that I couldn't agree more with a_horse_with_no_name. What a sloppy mess to deal with and that's just a simple update statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How a_horse_with_no_name said.

```
psql -U postgres -d dbName -c "UPDATE \"user\" SET \"password\" = 'test'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar recently.
What you want to do is preform the logon first (`psql -U postgres -d ticketon -c`) and then pipe via STDIN the query you wish to preform (`"UPDATE "user" SET "password" = 'test'"`). In bash this will be the following:

```
    echo "UPDATE "user" SET "password" = 'test'" | psql -U postgres -d ticketon -c
```

The above could work better than just using the `-c` command for a single command, because postgres does not like dealing with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

No need for excessive quoting if you use an sh `here document`:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U postgres -d ticketon <<XXX
UPDATE "user"
SET password = 'test'
WHERE username = 'James' -- I think a where clause is needed here ...
   ;
XXX
```