# Pipe multiple SQL commands to psql CLI

Tags: postgresql, pipe, command-line-interface, sql-insert, psql

I have a set of linux applications that are being composed together via pipes

```
some_application | awk '{print "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (\x27" $2 "\x27," $3 ")"'
```

The output of which will be a series of SQL `INSERT` commands:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('foo',42)
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('bar',43)
```

**How can these multiple commands be piped into `psql`?**

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656217/postgres-update-command-from-cli) which answers how to execute a single command using the `-c` parameter for psql.  But that answer is not ideal for my scenario because it requires establishing a new connection for each command; I would prefer to setup a single connection and then pipe all commands through that one session.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Take a look at example [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) under ```-c command``` to see if that will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pipe it into `psql` directly, but you need semicolon terminators for each line.

```
some_application | awk '{print "INSERT INTO my_table (\'" $2 "\'," $3 ");"' | psql <your connection switches>
```

You can test your connection parms by doing something innocuous like so:

```
echo "select count(*) from pg_tables;" | psql <your parms>
```

You will see the result of the query if the connection information is correct.